# How Can Ibinding data from parent component to child component?

Tags: angular

I have a parent component has many properties, and I need every time to use some component child, firstly I worked with conditions when I need the main component I make the variable dashboardState == 'main'.

```
<div *ngIf="dashboardState === 'main'" class="col-12 p-0 p-md-1 h-100">
   <app-main-dahsboard [site]="site" [siteContent]="siteContent"></app-main-dahsboard>
</div>
```

but I know that is not a good idea because now I have more a lot of component child, so I search for a better way I find that I can work with router-outlet with children, it's one of the good ways, but I find a problem to share the properties that I have on the parent component, I have only one way is to create a Service and I will share all my data using this service.
or I can invoke child component every time I need them for example if I need component X I will invoke component X with destroying other components. like this way.

```
@ViewChild('container', { read: container }) container: ViewContainerRef;
onBuildChildCompoenent() {
  const componentRef = this.container.createComponent(componentChild);
  componentRef.instance.param01 = param01;
  componentRef.instance.param02 = param02;
  componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

what is the best way to work with a lot of child components and also I need to share a lot of properties with them? and of course, if you have another suggestion, please don't hesitate.

Comment: please edit the title as the main question isn't related to data binding.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to know a best practise to pass data from parent to child ?

Comment: @Emilien yes I search for the best practice to share or binding data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass data from parent to children, you have several ways :

@Input() :
In parent component template, put this

```html
<child [site]="site" [siteContent]="siteContent"></child>
```

And in `child-component` :

```js
@Input() site: any;
@Input() siteContent: any;
```

Why are you saying "now I have more a lot of component child".
You don't have any `*ngFor` or anything else to have several  tag.
Anyway, even if it's the case, that's not a bad thing.

---

With router-outlet :

```js
{
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/site', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'site',
        data: {
            some_data: 'value'
        },
        loadChildren: () => import('./home/site/site.module').then(m => m.SiteModule)
      },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }
    ]
}
```

Then in your `site-component` :

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.data.subscribe(console.log);
}
```

Comment: if we shared data in router-outlet, I think there isn't a big difference with share data using a service because I have more then 50 children and every child has 3 to 5 five properties I load them inside parent component, what do you think? I want just to optimize the code and use the best practice.

Comment: If the data shared are constants values, it will work the same using a router-outlet or a service. But if the datas shared are variables, it will not work because the datas will not be persisted.